# Data attribute in HTML

Tags: html

What does this means? And how to decode the data?
`data="B64ENCeyJCdXkiOjI3LCJPdmVyIjoyLCJIb2xkIjozLCJVbmRlcnBlcmZvcm0iOjAsIlNlbGwiOjB9"`

Code from where I extracted this is:

```
<div 
  class="wsod_silo"
  data="B64ENCeyJCdXkiOjI3LCJPdmVyIjoyLCJIb2xkIjozLCJVbmRlcnBlcmZvcm0iOjAsIlNlbGwiOjB9"
  date="August 2020"
  id="wsod_ar7"
  style="width:32.75px;left:229.25px;">
</div>
```

Comment: It doesn't look like your pasted link worked, where you retrieved the code from.

Answer (score 2):

It is a base 64 encoded string. When you remove the `B64ENC` from the start you get

```
{"Buy":27,"Over":2,"Hold":3,"Underperform":0,"Sell":0}
```

```js
var encodedString = 'eyJCdXkiOjI3LCJPdmVyIjoyLCJIb2xkIjozLCJVbmRlcnBlcmZvcm0iOjAsIlNlbGwiOjB9';
var decodedString = atob(encodedString);
console.log(decodedString);
```

Answer (score 1):

That means something is stored into some `DOM` element data encoded using `Base64`.
You have to skip first part of string `B64ENC` and use rest of string and decode it.

For example, let put some `button` to decode it using `js`, and I put `id` for that `div` so we can use it in `js` easiest:

```js
function dc() {
  //take complete string from data of DIV
  var div = document.getElementById('dd').getAttribute('data');
  //remove B64ENC part from string
  //string B64ENC length is 6 chars, so we take rest of string from position 6 (because substr 1st string is zero position)
  var ss = div.substr(6, div.length-6);
  //decode Base64 string
  var dc = atob(ss);
  //show result of decoded string
  document.getElementById('spResult').innerHTML = dc;
  //You can realize that decoded string is some JSON value string
}
```

```html
<div id="dd" 
class="wsod_silo" data="B64ENCeyJCdXkiOjI3LCJPdmVyIjoyLCJIb2xkIjozLCJVbmRlcnBlcmZvcm0iOjAsIlNlbGwiOjB9" date="August 2020" id="wsod_ar7" style="width:32.75px;left:229.25px;"> </div>
<input type="button" value="Decode DIV data value" onclick="dc();" />
<span id="spResult"></span>
```